# Concurrency Model C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

Suppose you are given the following code:

```
class FooBar {
  public void foo() {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      print("foo");
    }
  }

  public void bar() {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      print("bar");
    }
  }
}
```

The same instance of `FooBar` will be passed to two different threads. Thread A will call `foo()` while thread B will call `bar()`. Modify the given program to output "foobar" n times.

For the following problem on leetcode we have to write two functions

```
void foo(function<void()> printFoo);
void bar(function<void()> printBar);
```

where `printFoo` and correspondingly `printBar` is a function pointer that prints Foo. The functions `foo` and `bar` are being called in a multithreaded environment and there is no ordering guarantee on how `foo` and `bar` is being called.

My solution was

```
class FooBar {
private:
    int n;
    mutex m1;
    condition_variable cv;
    condition_variable cv2;
    bool flag;
public:
    FooBar(int n) {
        this->n = n;
        flag=false;
    }

    void foo(function<void()> printFoo) {

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            unique_lock<mutex> lck(m1);
            cv.wait(lck,[&]{return !flag;});
            printFoo();
            flag=true;
            lck.unlock();
            cv2.notify_one();
        }
    }

    void bar(function<void()> printBar) {

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            unique_lock<mutex> lck(m1);
            cv2.wait(lck,[&]{return flag;});
            printBar();
            flag=false;
            lck.unlock();
            cv.notify_one();

            // printBar() outputs "bar". Do not change or remove this line.

        }
    }
};
```

Let us assume, at time `t = 0` bar was called and then at time `t = 10` foo was called, foo goes through the critical section protected by the mutex `m1`.

My question are

Does the C++ memory model because of the fencing property guarantee that when the `bar` function resumes from waiting on `cv2` the value of flag will be set to true?

Am I right in assuming locks shared among threads enforce a before and after relationship as illustrated in the manner of Leslie Lamports clocking system. The compiler and C++ guarantees everything before the end of a critical section (Here the end of the lock) will be observed will be observed by any thread that renters the lock, so common locks, atomics, semaphore can be visualised as enfocing before and after behavior by establishing time in multithreaded environment.

Can we solve this problem using just one condition variable?

Is there a way to do this without using locks and just atomics. What performance improvements do atomics give over locks?

What happens if i do `cv.notify_one()` and correspondigly `cv2.notify_one()` within the critical region, is there a chance of a missed interrupt.

Original Problem
https://leetcode.com/problems/print-foobar-alternately/.

Leslie Lamports Paper 
https://lamport.azurewebsites.net/pubs/time-clocks.pdf

Answer (score 0):

> Does the C++ memory model because of the fencing property guarantee that when the bar function resumes from waiting on cv2 the value of flag will be set to true?

By itself, a conditional variable is prone to spurious wake-up.  A `CV.wait(lck)` call without a predicate clause can return for kinds of reasons.  That's why it's always important to check the predicate condition in a while loop before entering `wait`. You should never assume that when `wait(lck)` returns that the thing you were waiting for has actually happened.  But with the clause you added within the wait: `cv2.wait(lck,[&]{return flag;});` this check is taken care of for you.  So yes, when `wait(lck, predicate)` returns, then  `flag` will be true.

> Can we solve this problem using just one condition variable?

Absolutely.  Just get rid of `cv2` and have both threads wait (and notify) on the first `cv`.

> Is there a way to do this without using locks and just atomics. What performance improvements do atomics give over locks?

atomics are great when you can get away with polling on one thread instead of waiting. Imagine a UI thread that wants to show you the current speed of your car.  And it polls the `speed` variable on every frame refresh.  But another thread, the "engine thread" is setting that `atomic<int> speed` variable with every rotation of the tire.  That's where it shines - when you already have a polling loop in place, and on x86, atomics are mostly implemented with the LOCK op code prefix (e.g. concurrency is done correctly by the CPU).

As for an implementation for just locks and atomics... well, it's late for me.  Easy solution, both threads just sleep and poll on an atomic integer that increments with each thread's turn.  Each thread just waits for value to be "last+2" and polls every few milliseconds.  Not efficient, but would work.

It's a bit late in the evening for me to thing about how to do this with a single or pair of mutexes.

> What happens if i do cv.notify_one() and correspondigly cv2.notify_one() within the critical region, is there a chance of a missed interrupt.

No, you're fine.  As long as all your threads are holding a lock and checking their predicate condition before entering the `wait` call.  You can do the `notify` call insider or outside of the critical region.  I always recommend doing `notify_all` over `notify_one`, but that might even be unnecessary.

Comment: Some extra questions

Comment: @Varun - I don't know what your extra questions are. In any case, Stack Overflow isn't really a discussion channel. It better serves users who can summarize their programming problem into a single question.  So I can't really spend any more time on this question - especially if you are moving the goal posts after I got you to the 1 yard line.  At some point, you just kinda gotta do your own homework.

Comment: stackoverflow didnt allow me to edit my question, I just wanted to clarify assuming no spurious wakeups the other thread sees the right value of the flag because of the fencing property of the memory model?

Comment: As long as you are accessing the variable under a lock, you will always be guaranteed to be seeing the correct version of the variable. There's a concept called the "cache coherency issue" when you access data outside of a lock on multi-core machines and might not see the latest update for several cycles.  Locks help invalidate the cache so that this can't happen.